# How to use regex in python to find the pattern "numberxnumber" in a string

Tags: python

I have a column containing the following strings :

****DSP_campaign_region_market_ MO_0_Device_Display_Open Web_0_0_0_PROS_DSP Custom HH Ext_160x600_0_DYN_FLTKG_010121-123121_SP_PID=111112220202043**

**DSP_campaign_region_market_0_Device_video_Open Web_0_0_0_PROS_DSP Custom HH Ext_160x600_0__PID=11172045203353_DYN_FLTKG_010121-123121_MP****

I need to extract the creative sizes such as 160x600, 1x1 from the strings shown above

I n basically split all the strings in the column by "_" and append empty lists add them as columns,

```
 campaign=[]
 dsp = []
 market=[]
 region =[]
 device_type=[]
 channel=[]
 creative = []
 for i in mapper['string_column']:
     i = str(i)
     i = i.split("_")
     dsp.append(i[0].replace("  ",''))
     campaign.append(i[1])
     region.append(i[2])
     market.append(i[3])
     device_type.append(i[5])
     channel.append(i[6])
     **creative.append(i[13])**
```

However, due to the lack of symmetry between the naming of the strings, some (when split by "_") have i[13] as **160x600** while others have **DSP Custom HH**

So, is there a way to use regex to identify creative size parts of the string such as 160X600, 1X1, 720X90 etc instead of splitting the string?

Comment: that's a fairly easy regex. why don't you try it yourself

Comment: Please don't post your HW right away here on stackoverflow without trying.

Comment: And just refrence it can be found using- ```import re;
string = "This was my numberxnumber, I'am repeating it again numberxnumber, bye!";
print(re.findall(r"\D{6}x\D{6}", string));``` And if you didn't knew it already, here's a fact you can use semicolons(;) in python

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with regex and without splitting the initial strings. Something like this:

```
import re

texts = ["DSP_campaign_region_market_ MO_0_Device_Display_Open Web_0_0_0_PROS_DSP Custom HH Ext_160x600_0_DYN_FLTKG_010121-123121_SP_PID=111112220202043", "DSP_campaign_region_market_0_Device_video_Open Web_0_0_0_PROS_DSP Custom HH Ext_160x600_0__PID=11172045203353_DYN_FLTKG_010121-123121_MP"]

pattern = "\d+x\d+"

for text in texts:
    occurences = re.findall(pattern, text)
    for item in occurences:
        print(item)

#> 160x600
#> 160x600
```